# New to OOP, manage variables in classes

Tags: java, oop

So. I got a mission from my teacher to make a program that manages different students. The program will hold the name, education, information and points.

You will have the option to:

- Add new students
- Change education and information
- Manage points

Making new students is not a problem, but managing education, info and points for specific students is the hard part, that's where I need your help. My main.java does not contain anything for now.

---

Student.java

```
package student;
public class Student {
    String namn;
    String program;
    String info;
    int points;

public void managePoints(){

}
public void changeProgram(){

}
public void changeInfo(){

}

}
```

---

Main.java

```
package student;
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Comment: What those methods supposed to do? Give more information.

Comment: Lets say we make a new student, with 5 points, education is "TEINF", info is empty and a unique name. When i.e using managePoints() will override current points with points desired, same with all other methods. The user will have a inputbox (textbox) inputting the new values

Comment: You  need to have more methods and implementations to get the things done. Maintain a List of students. Have Id to them and that id will be index too.. etc

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly know what do you want to actually do but your `Student` class (if I think correctly what you will need) should look more like this:

```
public class Student {
    private String  name; // private because you don't want anyone to interact with the variable too much.
    private String  program;
    private String  info;
    private int     points;

    public Student( String name, String program, String info, int points ) { // contructor with variables to initialize. You can remove some of the variables if you do not consider they should be here.
        this.name = name;
        this.program = program;
        this.info = info;
        this.points = points;
        // without `this` you would change parameter's value to itself which isn't what you want.
    }

    public String getName( ) { // getter because I guess you would like to know students name
        return name;
    }

    public int getPoints( ) {
        return points;
    }

    public void addPoints( int points ) { // setter so you can modify points
        this.points += points;
    }

    public String getProgram( ) { // same as getName
        return program;
    }

    public void setProgram( String program ) {
        this.program = program;
    }

    public String getInfo( ) {
        return info;
    }

    public void setInfo( String info ) {
        this.info = info;
    }
}
```

But how to use these methods?  You use them as the example below shows

```
Student s1 = new Student("Abc Xyz", "IT", "Some informations", 12);
Student s2 = new Student("Cba Zyx", "Some other program", "Some more informations, 0);

s2.setInfo( s1.getInfo( ) );
s1.setPoints(1234);
s2.setProgram("Axbzcy");
```

Getter is a method which returns (most likely) private variable's value.
Setter is a method which sets private variable's value to another value which is passed as a parameter to the method.

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments, I guess the three methods in your class are supposed to change the points, program and info of the student to a desired value. In Java, we call these *setters*.

You should rename your methods to `setPoints`, `setProgram` and `setInfo`. It's a pattern, you know.

Next, how are you going to know the "desired" value of those fields? You might say, I get them from the text boxes in the methods. But a better approach would be to get the values from another method and pass the value to the setters as a *parameter*.

To add a parameter to your methods, add a variable-like thingy in the brackets of the method declaration:

```
public void setPoints (int p)
```

And for the `setInfo`

```
public void setInfo (String i)
```

And so on.

In the method bodies, you set the fields to the parameters. E.g. In the `setInfo` method you write

```
info = i;
```

I think you can figure out the others.

Now how do you use these methods? For instance, suppose you have a student variable called `student`. And you got the info of him/her and stored it in a string variable called `studentInfo`. You can set the student variable's `info` to `studentInfo` by

```
student.setInfo (studentInfo);
```

Or if you don't want to use a variable, you can just use a string literal.

```
student.setInfo("this is my info. Blah blah blah");
```

Answer (score 0):

Final code:

```
package student;
// The student class definition
public class Student {
   private String name;
   private String address;
   private String info;
   private String kurs;
   private int points;


   // Constructor
   public Student(String name, String address, String info, String kurs, int points) {
      this.name = name;
      this.address = address;
      this.points = points;
      this.kurs = kurs;
      this.info = info;

   }

   // Public getter for private variable name
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   // Public getter for private variable address
   public String getAddress() {
      return address;
   }
      public String getInfo() {
      return info;
   }
         public int getPoints() {
      return points;
   }

   // Public setter for private variable address
   public void setAddress(String address) {
      this.address = address;
   }
   public void setPoints(int points){
       this.points = points;
   }
   public void setInfo(String info){
       this.info = info;
   }
   public void setKurs(String kurs){
       this.kurs = kurs;
   }

   // Describe itself
   public String toString() {
      return name + ", Adress: " + address + ", Info: " + info + ", Kurs: " + kurs + ", Poäng: " + points +" ";
   }

}
```

Main

```
package student;

// A test driver program for the Student class
public class main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Student ArHa = new Student("A H", "Jysgaan 61", "ADHD", "Teknik", 5);
      ArHa.setPoints(10);
      ArHa.setKurs("TEINF");
     System.out.println(ArHa);
      Student DaSk = new Student("Dael Sklbr", "Fegea 65", "Svart", "Teknik", 5);
      DaSk.setInfo("Riktigt svart");
     System.out.println(DaSk);
      Student FaMe = new Student("Falafel Medusa", "Fågel 123", "Maten", "Kock", 123);
     System.out.println(FaMe);
   }
}
```

Thank you everyone for the help.